# iOS 8: Get title of song being played by the system music player

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to get the title of the song currently being played by the default Music app. Here is the method:

```
- (NSString*)getSongTitle {
  MPMediaItem *currentSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
  _title = [currentSong valueForProperty:@"MPMediaGroupingTitle"];
  NSLog(_title);
  return _title;
}
```

Everything I have read online says that this should be correct, but `_title` gets assigned `nil` every time. Any ideas?

I have @imported `MediaPlayer` by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just using the wrong key. Try `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle`. It should look something like this:

```
- (NSString*)getSongTitle {
  MPMediaItem *currentSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
  _title = [currentSong valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
  NSLog(_title);
  return _title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (NSString*)getSongTitle {
  MPMediaItem *currentSong = [[MPMusicPlayerController systemMusicPlayer] nowPlayingItem];
  _title = currentsong.title;
  NSLog(_title);
  return _title;
}
```